# How to use types/select2 in a Angular 2 project?

Tags: angular, typescript, jquery-select2, definitelytyped

I am developing Angular 2 project with Typescript. I want to be able to use select2 and I don't see any stable feature rich plugins equivalent to select2. However I came across `types/select2` in [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/6fce8b630d1618c2436d2f1e67e94f78da8d29d2/types/select2) project. I'm not sure how to use them in my project. I can't find examples of other DefinitelyTyped libraries also. I'm new to both TS and Angular 2. Can someone provide pointers on how I should used this ?

I understand I can include the library using my package.json but no idea how I can use in a component.

Comment: See if this link can help you https://embed.plnkr.co/gHZKfFbTuTJY8lX5BG7o/

Comment: Your examples seems to be using the jQuery library directly. Thank you for setting that Plunkr. I'm looking to find how to use types/select2 from DefinitelyTyped. There are a bunch of other libraries there that I might want to use later. So looking to find the right way...

Answer (score 4):

With @types/select2 installed, it allows the typescript compiler to do static type checking to ensure the Select2 library is being called correctly. It does not change the way you use the `select2` - you still need to install the `Select2` library and use it as you would have without type checking.

For external dependencies (like jQuery or Select2) you should install their corresponding type definition files, so that the typescript compiler can resolve the external types at compile-time.  This is preferred over declaring an `any` types (i.e. `declare var $: any`)

Make sure you install jQuery types as well :

```
npm install @types/jquery
```

This will install the type definitions under `node_modules/@types/jQuery`. By default, the typescript compiler will resolve types from the `node_modules/@types` folder.

For TypeScript NodeJS packages, you can generate type definition files as part of the compilation step and specify `index.d.ts` in the `typings` property of your `package.json` file. In this case, you don't necessarily need to export the type definitions to `node_modules/@types`.

Comment: So the types/<any_library> is only for type checking and they do not provide any integration of the jquery plugins to easily use with Angular 2?

Comment: Yes, it is only for type checking.

Comment: Angular2 uses module loaders. Any libraries that use module loaders can use the `package` way of specifying the type definition files.  Libraries like jQuery and Select2 use the traditional way of loading files - through the `script` tag from `index.html`.  That's why referencing the type definition files is a bit different.

Comment: On the whole this is a good answer but you should provide an example of how to load jQuery and select2 as modules.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by importing:

```
import 'select2';
```

which I had installed earlier:

```
npm install select2 --save
```

Once you've done that, you can use the library through jquery as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by

```
import { Select2 } from 'select2'
```

and also install:

```
npm install @types/select2@4.0.48
```

Now i have to run test but no more errors on Typescript slint